# Как создать библиотеку в C++ и использовать её функции в Matlab?

Tags: matlab, c++

Как создать библиотеку в C++ и использовать её функции в Matlab?
Идея в том, чтобы написать функцию на C++ с использованием OpenCL, а использовать этот код в Matlab.
(Меня не интересуют готовые OpenCL и Cuda решения для Matlab)

Comment: Обнаружил интересную информацию по MEX файлам и Matlab AddIn for Visual Studio. Но всё равно было бы интересно поглядеть мануальчик какой-нибудь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого потребуется создать исполняемый MEX-файл. Подробнее здесь:

- [How can I interface MATLAB code with C, C++, or FORTRAN?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1622.html)
- [C++ with Matlab Tutorial](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~dip/lecture/C++_with_Matlab.pdf)